# AJAX POST Browser History

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html, browser-history

i'm having a very annoying problem that didn't figure out yet.

I'm developing a Web system using "Single Page Application Paradigm", but without any framework like angular, backbone, etc.

We load the page once and almost all other pages are load via ajax. The problem starts when we the user click on the Back button of Browser.
Since there is no page reload, after the user login in the system, no url is changed and when the users try do use the back button from the browser, he's redirected to login page, cause it's the last page he "visited".

All the content is load via ajax post (not very proud of) and now we must support the back/foward button. I tryed using HTML5 History API but with no success. I was able to register the 'popstate' callback and tryed to simulate a post again. But there are fields in the page that i must restore. I'm not sure if i can find it but what i need is like to restore the page to the state before the request was sent, like a snapshot.

Can anyone give me a hand ?

Thanks! (I'm desperate :D)

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel. Look into a framework like angular. Otherwise, consider localStorage/history API.

Comment: Well, i agree with you. The problem is that i'm not familiar with Angular yet and we didn't have the time to learn it. The project is almost 90% done and we kind need to add this feature ASAP.

Comment: Have a look at an example SPA like Kendo-UI's [WebSushi](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/websushi/). Their code is pretty simple and demonstrates the basics very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example of how to do it:

```
var state = null;
$(document).ready(function($) {   
//this is my menu... I created a simple menu just for testing :)
    $('nav li').on('click', function(){
        var title = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        loadPage(title);
        window.history.pushState(title, null, '#'+title);
    });


    window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
        state = event.state;
        console.log("State: "+state);
        if(state != null && state != "null"){
            loadPage(state);
        }
    });
});

function loadPage(page) {
    $("#content").load(page+".html");
}
```

Cheers ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using the fragment identifier (stuff after the # in a URL) to keep track of what "page" you're on, and this is what some frameworks do. Most browsers can listen for changes to that, and the browser history plays nice with it, so you can retrieve the value when it changes and take appropriate action.

Comment: But the browser will be able to restore the entire page (even those parts that didn't change via ajax) ?

Comment: Yes, suppose you have URLs ending in #page1, #page2, #page3, etc. If you listen for the fragment changing, which could be triggered by hitting the back button, you retrieve which "page" you are on, and then you initiate the appropriate AJAX request (or pull from cached JS object or whatever) and then populate the page. This may require significant rework in your application, but it should work.